# Iterating through table for IDW says parameters are not valid?

Tags: arcpy, inverse-distance-weighted, geostatistical-analyst

I have a table with precipitation data from 5 weather stations and I am trying to iterate through the table to perform IDW on each field (month of precipitation).

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("GeoStats")
env.workspace = "C:\Users\Lab R220\Desktop\Riley"
arcpy.env.extent = "Thames_watershed.shp"
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields("stationswithprecip.shp")


for field in fieldList:
    try:
        outraster = str(field.name) + ".tiff"
        arcpy.IDW_ga("stationswithprecip.shp", field.name, outraster, 1, 2)
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
        pass
```

The error I am receiving are as follows:

Executing: IDW "C:\Users\Lab R220\Desktop\Riley\stationswithprecip.shp" id id.tiff "C:\Users\Lab R220\Desktop\Riley\1" 2 2 "NBRTYPE=Standard S_MAJOR=25461.6476799568 S_MINOR=25461.6476799568 ANGLE=0 NBR_MAX=15 NBR_MIN=10 SECTOR_TYPE=ONE_SECTOR" #
Start Time: Mon Jul 22 09:36:46 2019
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000361: The name starts with an invalid character

However if I run the months through the IDW tool individually they work. I have 120 of these so I would rather not run them one by one.

My field names look like this with the numbers increasing by 1  "Jan2008" and they are all double

Comment: Do you have any other fields on that shapefile besided the `precip` ones? You can use a wildcard in the `arcpy.ListFields()` to limit the returned fields and get just the ones that start with `precip`. It looks like it is taking all the fields, including SHAPE and OBJECTID.

Comment: Yes I do but I get the error for every single field. I get about 120 of those error messages when I run the code. I figured the OBJECTID wouldn't work so I threw in the except : pass so I could just skip over those columns and on to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

```
arcpy.IDW_ga("stationswithprecip.shp", field.name, **""**, outraster, 1, 2)
```

The problem was in my parameter list. It was naming each file 1 which is supposed to be the cell size. I added the "" and now it works